# Is it bad practice in angular to mock a service via reassigning properties, instead of registering a replacement service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-service

Given a service `someService` that returns an object with 3 functions on it: `fn1`, `fn2`, `fn3`

In most cases I am mocking out my services by doing something similar to this:

(1)

```
module(function($provide) {
    var someServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('someService', ['fn1', 'fn2']);
    $provide.factory('someService', function() {
        return someServiceMock;
    });
});

//value of someService: {fn1: fakeSpy, fn2: fakeSpy2}
```

The advantage of this is that you are completing replacing any behavior of `someService` with this mock, and it is equally easy, whether the service returns a function, object, etc.

But I figured out I can also end up with a service with spy's on `fn1` and `fn2` by doing this:

(2)

```
inject(function($injector){
    var service = $injector.get('someService');

    var someServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('someService', ['fn1', 'fn2']);

    _.assign(service, someServiceMock);
});

//value of someService: {fn1: fakeSpy, fn2: fakeSpy2, fn3: realFn3}
```

The disadvantage of this is that I don't think you could mock out services that return functions with this way.

Edit: I think you could still make this work with services returning functions, by just using `spyOn` the function.

But The advantage of this second way is that if you wanted to mock out ALL the functions and use spy's, and then just replace the functions that need special behavior, then you easily could do that, like in (3).

(3)

```
inject(function($injector){
    var service = $injector.get('someService');

    var serviceFns = _.functions(service);

    var someServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('someService', serviceFns);
    _.assign(service, someServiceMock);
});

//value of someService: {fn1: fakeSpy, fn2: fakeSpy2, fn3: fakeSpy3}
```

So then I'm wondering if it's considered bad practice to override services, factories, etc. using the strategies in (2) and (3), when unit testing, or are both ways ok?

Comment: How about injecting the actual service instance, and spying on the functions that need to be mocked? That's what I find the most elegant.

Comment: Yes, that would be another way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, now that I'm trying the code, I do like your idea @JBNizet to spy on the functions, rather than creating a new spy object, because then that would allow you to use callThrough on the actual instance (and do various other spy things on the function). It doesn't feel as hacky as what I suggested.

Comment: I've actually now been trying to use a decorator to add spies to the service im trying to mock and then returning that service, and it seems to be working pretty well and I don't think there are any pitfalls.